# Change the color of the last item in a list view affecting the first item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I'm trying to change the color of my last item in my listview, which is fine, it's working, but when I scroll back the first item of the listview is also changed, I don't know why this is happening, here is my code:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_user, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.icon);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(lista[position]);

        if (position == lista.length -1) {

            holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.title.setTextColor(0xFF999999);
            holder.title.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);

        }

        return vi;
    }


    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the else part also like below

```
if (position == lista.length -1) {

    holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.title.setTextColor(0xFF999999);
    holder.title.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);

}else{   

    holder.title.setTextColor(otherColor);
}
```

Comment: While correct, an explanation is probably needed. The reason for this happening is that list items are recycled, i.e., the same item objects are re-used as you scroll through a list (convertView != null means an item was re-used). This in turn means that you should not rely on any default properties of an item but rather explicitly set all properties that could ever have been changed by any other item.

Comment: don't forget to add notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this happening is that list items are recycled, i.e., the same item objects are re-used for performance reasons as you scroll through a list (convertView != null means a previously inflated and decorated item was re-used and passed to you for re-decoration).

This in turn means that you should not rely on any default properties of an item but rather explicitly set all properties that could ever have been changed by any other item, as suggested in [@uday's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32586234/1226020).